# Compass with bitmap is going everywhere in the screen

Tags: android

i want my compass to spin like this

[image]

but my result is that:

[image]

the compass is going everywhere in my screen...

where is my problem please?this is my compass.java code:

```
 @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
            int w = canvas.getWidth();
            int h = canvas.getHeight();
            int cw = w / 2;
            int ch = h / 2;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass);

            canvas.translate(cw, ch);   
            if (mValues != null) {
                canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
            } 
            int cx = (mWidth - myBitmap.getWidth()) / 2;
            int cy = (mHeight - myBitmap.getHeight()) / 2;

            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, cx, cy, null);
        }
```

p.s.: i m sorry for the bad pictures but i really dont know how to explain my problem in english!Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already translated to the center of the canvas, you may only need to offset the compass with its half width/height to center it. Try:

```
int cx = -myBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
int cy = -myBitmap.getHeight() / 2;

canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, cx, cy, null);
```

Also to get a good hang of transformations (translate, rotate), read The [OpenGL Red book chapter 3](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html), specifically the part **Thinking about Transformations**. While this is about OpenGL, you can use the knowledge for non-OpenGL transforms too.

EDIT:

Think in turtle logic. Your first translation takes your pencil to the center of your canvas. The rotation rotates your pencil. So now you could draw the compass exactly where the pencil is (no offsets), except that drawing the compass image is done starting from its top-left corner instead of its center. Therefore you need a last translation of (-compassWidth/2, -compassHeight/2). Note that this translation already occurs on the rotated x & y axes. Also note that you may pass 0/0 for cx/cy in drawBitmap if you manually apply that translation to the canvas itself.

So the full sequence is: translate to canvas center, rotate, translate negated to image center.

Comment: do you mean canvas.rotare(-mValues[0],cx,cy); ?

Comment: @kgr: No, rotation may be ok as is. you should modify the cx/cy valus for the drawBitmap call as written if I assume right.

Answer (score 0):

Don't decode the Bitmap in onDraw - do it when the view is created and reuse the Bitmap.

Make a Matrix and `matrix.postRotate(mValues[0], half_width_of_bitmap, half_height_of_bitmap);` and `matrix.postTranslate(cw, ch);`

Draw the bitmap with `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);`